# How to change textview item color from another class?

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, textview

I have one big problem ( for me ) 
I have some items from api in RecycleViewHolder.class in that class i tell where is xml file of that items.. Now my problem is because i have preference settings in mainactivity and when i define background color to black of whole app my text will be in the same color "black" and i can not see anything in app because of colour. Now i need your help how to change colour of textview in mainactivity,when i try to make findviewbyid in MainActivity and call method setTextColor I get nullpointexception because it is already connected to xml in  RecycleViewHolder Class.
This is RecyclceViewHolder class that contains textview of price that i wanna to change colour from mainactivity.

```html
package com.example.domo.cryptotrace;


import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;


/**
 * Created by Antun on 31.1.2018..
 */
public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{



    public TextView name, symbol, rank, percentChange1h, percentChange24h, percentChange7d;
    public TextView price;



    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        symbol= itemView.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
        rank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.
                rank);
        price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        percentChange1h=itemView.findViewById(R.id.percent_change_1h);
        percentChange24h=itemView.findViewById(R.id.percent_change_24h);
        percentChange7d=itemView.findViewById(R.id.percent_change_7d);


        

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       
    }



}
```

This is mainactivity (in this class i wanna change
RecyclerViewHolder --> itemView--> price color)

```html
package com.example.domo.cryptotrace;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import java.util.List;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Button register;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
                .kits(new Crashlytics())
                .debuggable(true)
                .build();
        Fabric.with(fabric);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getUserList();

        
        register=findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginSys.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        

    }




  

    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreference();

    }



    //Ovo je klasa koju smo sami gore kreirali kako bi mogli odrediti boje od pozadine kroz Settings
    //Tu još možeš i mjenjati text boju od texViewa sa metodom ||myTextView.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);||
    //Ili ovako ||ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);||
    private void getPreference() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (preferences.contains("color")) {
            if (preferences.getString("color", "0").equals("1")) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else if (preferences.getString("color", "0").equals("2")) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else if (preferences.getString("color","0").equals("3")){
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }else{
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);



            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.your_item_id) {
            //A ovo je metoda za pozivanje i startanje preferences activity-a
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void getUserList() {
        try {
            APIService service = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(APIService.class);
            Call<List<User>> call = service.getUserData();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
                    //Log.d("onResponse", response.message());

                    List<User> userList = response.body();
                   LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

                    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

                    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter =
                            new RecyclerViewAdapter(userList);

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e) {}

    }
}
```

So one more time,
I need code to change color of textview item of price from RecyclerViewHolder class.

Thank for all help, every good point of answer will be credited with thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use color as a recyclerview constructor:

```
int color;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter =
                        new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, userList, color);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private Context context;
public static List<UserList> userList;
private int color;

public UserAdapter(Context context, List<UserList> userList, int color){
    super();
    //Getting all the superheroes
    this.color = color;
    this.userList = userList;
    this.context = context;
}
 @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {    
 holder.colorText.setText(mColorText.setText);
//here you will change the text color from mainactivity
   // this change color
    holder.colorText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,color));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView colorText;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();

    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you got me but can you please more explain how to use it ? and where to put codes ..

Comment: How i can change color of RecycleViewHolder -- ItemView--Price in mainactivity if i put your code in it?

Comment: I added an edit. About viewing takes care of onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Mate i already have that class and i still can not change colour from other activity, have you saw my code of recycleviewholder and mainactivity, i have constructor in class User i added color int to it.. and i have recycleviewadapter.class here is code:
https://pastebin.com/zbr6ejJF

My question is how from main acitvity change colour of textview from RecycleViewHolder -- Want to change --> holder.price --> green from mainactivity where is class getPreference or from onCreate main class. 

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get into your code but I think you could create another TextView in your .xml file with an id like "priceColored" or something.

When you will want to change the price's color, you simply do:

```
price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceColored);
```

The TextView with the id priceColored will have the color you want to use. If you need to figure out how to create a textview of a certain color in android, you can find it very easily online.

Hope it helps,

Comment: That doesn't help me as i want to edit color of RecycleViewHolder price item. If i write 
price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
in MainActivity i get error. So i need to edit colour of textview from RecycleViewHolder.class in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

In RecyclerViewHolder class make one public method with color arguments and that method used in mainactivity with that class object and call that public method and pass your color code.

Make below method in RecyclerViewHolder.

```
    public void changeColor(int color){
    price.setTextColor(color)
}
```

and call this method in mainActivity

```
    RecyclerViewHolderobject.changeColor(Color.BLACK)
```

Comment: It don't works as i can not connect mainactivity to that method . 
I tried RecycleViewHolder.changeColor.changeColor(Color.BLACK);
Do i do something wrong with calling method from recycleviewholder?